# rss parsing using dom, html format tags

Tags: android, dom, html-parsing, domparser

i have to parse a RSS feed and display the same in android. i am using a DOM parser. i am able to parse all the tag except for the tag that has html formatting tags. for example

```
<description>
<p><span style="font-family: arial, geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">

<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; max-width: 600px; margin-top: 8px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 8px; margi

<strong>WILL YOUR KIDS LOVE ROCK OF AGES AS MUCH AS YOU WILL?</strong>&nbsp;We think they will have a great time, but you should know that he age of 14.</span></p>
</description>
```

Could some one please guide me how do I get the unformatted text content from that tag . Also, changing the RSS feed is not an option...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use the DOM parser, and really shouldn't be either. Use the `SAXParser` class instead, check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583755/android-rest-xml-result-to-listview/3585575#3585575) with the linked tutorial.

Comment: @raqz What I'm saying is that you are able to do it with the SAXParser

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working for me..

Html.fromHtml("value")